# Is validation set used for updating neural network?

Tags: validation, machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, bigdata

I have a question of neural network

Let's say I have 60 training, 20 validation, and 20 test set. For each epoch, I run through the 60 training set samples while adjusting the weights on each sample and also calculating the error on each validation sample.

**So as I know, Weight updates occur in training set (Not validation set)**

But I heard separating validation set from training set is for avoiding over fitting.

Then my question is

If validation doesn't make any weights update in neural network, How can validation set help the neural network avoid overfitting?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you say it is not used to update the weights of a neural network, but it is used to *monitor* the progress of training. The first step into preventing overfitting is to detect it, and using a validation set provides an independent measure of how well the network is generalizing outside of the training set.

So for example, you can use the validation set to decide when to stop training (before it starts to overfit). If you do this just remember to use another set (a test set) to produce final evaluation metrics.

Answer (score 7):

Validation set is used for [model selection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_selection). Most of the time it's not clear from the beginning what architecture (neural network topology, the number of layers, choice and order of layers, etc) or hyperparameter values (learning rate, layer size, dropout probability, etc) will produce the best result.

It's logical to try different architectures and hyperparameters to choose the best model. But if you evaluate each model on a test set, it means you are making a decision based on the test set, hence test performance (e.g. accuracy) is no longer independent and captures how well the model generalizes. That's why it's common to pick aside another set, different from the test set, to validate on.

Also note that to detect *overfitting* or *underfitting* one needs to have both training and validation results, because training loss or accuracy alone doesn't tell anything. That's why validation is necessary to avoid overfitting (and not only).